# Store un-submitted data using Shared Preferences

Tags: java, android

I need to store data which hasn't been saved yet using `Shared Preferences`. To give a quick example, in my application I want that if the user filled the `sign-up` form and closed the application, his information will still be filled up when he *re-enters* the application. Would you suggest any tutorials?

Comment: you can use cached db or saving user data into app data in xml/json form.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I just want to store the information which hasn't been yet submitted

Answer (score 1):

You can save that data in Bundle using onSaveInstanceState 
e.g.

```
@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    textView.setText(savedInstanceState.getString(TEXT_VIEW_KEY));
}

// invoked when the activity may be temporarily destroyed, save the instance state here
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putString(GAME_STATE_KEY, gameState);
    outState.putString(TEXT_VIEW_KEY, textView.getText());

    // call superclass to save any view hierarchy
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, a good alternative but my question is how the scenario can be done using Shared Preferences.

Comment: share your sharedPreferences instance from application class in that way even after activity restarts it will not loose those.

Answer (score 0):

How about creating a [ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/ViewModel) for your activity , your signup activity for instance.
This `ViewModel` will be your handler for your `SharedPreferences` and for keeping track of your data , say the values of the username and password text fields.
now you can override the method  `onCleared()` and add there the implementation of writing to `SharedPreferences`.

in your activity you will need :

- listen to your text fields using `TextWatcher` and probably override `void afterTextChanged(Editable s)` (since the user might just close the app) and inside update your `ViewModel` with the current value.
- load data from your `ViewModel` in order to init your UI inside `OnCreate()` in case you have any data saved in your `SharedPreferences`.

> `onCleared()`
>
> - This method will be called when this ViewModel is no longer used and will be destroyed.